# Can Charon move the opponent whatever the height?

Tags: santorini

Charon allows you to move an adjacent opponent to the space directly opposed (using your builder as mirror point), before moving.

While playing Charon :

- Can I move the opponent accross different heights ? (for example, he's on a height2 space, I move him to the ground - It's a legit move usually)
- Can I move the opponent on a space he should not be able to move directly from the space he's in ? (from ground to height2 for example - not a legit move usually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at rules [here](https://roxley.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Santorini-Rulebook-Web-2016.08.14.pdf) its seems to be absolutely fine regardless of levels.

Full rules for Charon are :-

> Before your Worker moves, you may force a neighboring opponent Worker to the space directly on the other side of your Worker, if that space is unoccupied.

Note it does not say you are 'moving' your opponents worker.  It's 'forcing' them.   To me this would imply that usual movement rules do not apply so its possible to jump from ground level up 2.  Also the word 'move' is used in several other gods powers but not Charon.

The rules are also have a link to explaining each power in detail.  The [Video for Charon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UF7VVk8pO1A) also specifies that it is 'forced' and in the video example shows the forced worker being raised two levels.